# Launch an ec2 instance with cloudformation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch an ec2 instance using cloudformation.I created this json template but I get error Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.

```
{
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties" : {
      "ImageId" : "ami-08ddb3f251a88cf33",
      "InstanceType" : "t2.micro ",
      "KeyName" : "Stagingkey",
      "LaunchTemplate" : {
            "LaunchTemplateId" : "jen1",
            "LaunchTemplateName" : "Launchinstance",
            "Version":"V1"
      },
      "SecurityGroupIds" : [ "sg-055f49a32efd4238b" ],
      "SecurityGroups" : [ "jenkins_group" ],

}
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is there any other template for ap-south-1 region which I could use? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The error says it all: *At least one Resources member must be defined.*

The major sections of a template are:

- Parameters
- Mappings
- Resources
- Outputs

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Description": "My Stack",
    "Resources": {
        "MyInstance": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "ImageId": "ami-08ddb3f251a88cf33",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro ",
                "KeyName": "Stagingkey",
                "LaunchTemplate": {
                    "LaunchTemplateId": "jen1",
                    "LaunchTemplateName": "Launchinstance",
                    "Version": "V1"
                },
                "SecurityGroupIds": [
                    "sg-055f49a32efd4238b"
                ],
                "SecurityGroups": [
                    "jenkins_group"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to test it. For example, it is unlikely that you will define both `SecurityGroupIds` and `SecurityGroups`.

Answer (score 1):

All the properties you have entered are properties of an EC2 resource, which you need to declare. You have no resources block/a logical name for you resource, like so:

```
"Resources": {
"MyTomcatName": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
[...]
```